# Remove Re: Fwd: from Mail subjects

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to put up a regex to remove extra keywords from the mail subjects, added generally by mail composers like Fwd, Re: But not able to come up with a regex that can satisfy all these scenarios.

```
Fwd : Re : Re: Many
Re : Re: Many
Re:    Re: Many
Re: Many
Re: Many
RE: Presidential Ballots for Florida
RE: (no subject)
Request - should not match anything
this is the subject
Re: Fwd
```

I tried with this regex in Java:

```
subject.replaceAll("^.{0,3}:\s", "");
```

but this removes only the first match found. Any regex if it can satisfy most of the common scenarios, not all the above will be a great help as well. I found some regex for Python, but converting them into Java is quite a pain. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could remove all of them using `\b(?:Fwd|Re)\b(?:\s*:\s*)?` https://regex101.com/r/ZfPWdF/1

Comment: `subject = subject.replaceAll("(?mi)^(?:\\h*(?:fwd|re)\\h*)+:\\h*", "");`

Comment: A small amendment to my suggestion: `.replaceAll("(?mi)^\\h*(?:(?:fwd|re)\\h*:\\h*)+", "")`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/f72XFq/1). The last `Fwd` is not followed with a colon, thus, should stay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might remove the occurrences that are not only bound to the start of the string using:

```
\b(?:Fwd|Re)\b\h*(?::\h*)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5j3JLp/1)

**Note** that this will also match the last full line `Re: Fwd`

---

If `Fwd` should not be matched (so the colon is not optional) and bound to the start of the string:

```
^(?:(?:Fwd|Re)\h*:\h*)+
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:Fwd|Re)\h*:\h*` Match either `Fwd` or `Re` followed by a colon between optional horizontal whitespaces
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1+ times to get all occurrences

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nrDthZ/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/EWt7nS)

Example

```
String regex = "^(?:(?:Fwd|Re)\\h*:\\h*)+";
String string = "Fwd : Re : Re: Many\n"
     + "Re : Re: Many\n"
     + "Re:    Re: Many\n"
     + "Re: Many\n"
     + "Re: Many\n"
     + "RE: Presidential Ballots for Florida\n"
     + "RE: (no subject)\n"
     + "Request - should not match anything\n"
     + "this is the subject\n"
     + "Re: Fwd";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
String result = matcher.replaceAll("");

System.out.println(result);
```

Output

```
Many
Many
Many
Many
Many
Presidential Ballots for Florida
(no subject)
Request - should not match anything
this is the subject
Fwd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex, `((?mi)(fwd|re)\s*:\s*)`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Fwd : Re : Re: Many\n" + 
                "Re : Re: Many\n" + 
                "Re:    Re: Many\n" + 
                "Re: Many\n" + 
                "Re: Many\n" + 
                "RE: Presidential Ballots for Florida\n" + 
                "RE: (no subject)\n" + 
                "Request - should not match anything\n" + 
                "this is the subject\n" + 
                "Re: Fwd" ;
        
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("((?mi)(fwd|re)\\s*:\\s*)", ""));   
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Many
Many
Many
Many
Many
Presidential Ballots for Florida
(no subject)
Request - should not match anything
this is the subject
Fwd
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

1. `(?mi)` specifies [multiline and case-insensitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html).
2. `(fwd|re)` specifies `fwd` or `re`.
3. `\s*` specifies any number of whitespace characters.